# symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load WITHOUT LOSING RECORDS IN DATABASE

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, fixtures

I am new to Symfony+Doctrine, but fairly experienced with web application development in general (mostly using Zend Framework). I have started a new project using Symfony, and I'm loving it.

I've got a handful of fixtures in my /data/fixtures/ folder which get loaded whenever I update the schema and do a:

```
sf doctrine:build --all --and-load
```

The problem is, adding fixtures is really tedious, whereas my app interface is pretty quick to load data with. So, I load testing data into the database (using my app), but then whenever I make a change to the schema (and run the above statement), it reverts the data to just what's in the fixtures.

In the manual I read that the --and-append option would not overwrite the data in the database. But, the --all option says it resets the database.

Obviously if I delete a column from the schema then I would lose that information, but I just want to preserve my new records.

Sorry if I'm missing something very obvious. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Don't forget that you can easily grab data that you've entered into a fixtures file using sf doctrine:data-dump. Then you could replace your existing fixtures with that, for reload whenever you update the schema. It's good to have a decent set of fixtures for automated unit-testing, anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`

From the documentation (`symfony help doctrine:build`):

```
You can also generate only class files by using the --all-classes shortcut
option. When this option is used alone, the database will not be modified.

  ./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
```

Comment: ok, thanks everyone for your advice. I suppose just updating the models is the way to go, then manually altering the db structure. I know it would be a bit hard for doctrine to do that too, but I am a bit "starry eyed" at the moment, and figured there's probably nothing doctrine can't do.

Comment: hah! @ `there's probably nothing doctrine can't do`. Get ready for a long, slow, dreary comedown...

Answer (score 3):

I try to make sure my process for schema changes is smooth enough that I will make them as soon as I think they're necessary instead of putting them off. Nuking all the data I've been working with is a definite turn-off that will increase mental resistance and keep me using a problematic schema longer than I should.

So--I think **you're doing it right** with the fixtures you have, you just need to dump more (`symfony doctrine:data-dump`) of your UI-entered data into the fixtures before reloading.  You will have to rewrite or rebuild the fixtures for some schema changes, but that's just the way it is.  Investing in working fixtures gives you flexibility to make schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `build --all` drops the database and you lose the information that's in it. the `--and-load` loads whatever you have in your fixtures back into it. So as far as I know there isn't a single command to do what you're after. From what I've understood the `--and-load` and `--and-append` are similar, as you can run `doctrine:data-load` repeatedly as well and it won't erase existing data.

So, in short, to keep your data, don't run `build --all` but make changes to your database through SQL, update your schema, and then just re-generate the models.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the db changes via doctrine migrations or yourself via sql scripts (which is IMO the safer option) or manually in the DB if you're developing. Typically I just rebuild the model classes to reflect the new schema changes (via doctrine:build) and just do a full db drop and recreate periodically to make sure everything works ok.